# How to detect attribute changes from model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to create a callback function in rails that executes after a model is saved.

I have this model, Claim that has a attribute 'status' which changes depending on the state of the claim, possible values are pending, endorsed, approved, rejected

The database has 'state' with the default value of 'pending'.

I'd like to perform certain tasks after the model is created on the first time or updated from one state to another, depending on which state it changes from.

My idea is to have a function in the model:

```
    after_save :check_state

    def check_state
      # if status changed from nil to pending (created)
      do this

      # if status changed from pending to approved
      performthistask
     end
```

My question is how do I check for the previous value before the change within the model?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You should look at [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) module.
You should be able to perform following actions on your `Claim` model:

```rb
claim.status_changed?  # returns true if 'status' attribute has changed
claim.status_was       # returns the previous value of 'status' attribute
claim.status_change    # => ['old value', 'new value'] returns the old and 
                       # new value for 'status' attribute

claim.name = 'Bob'
claim.changed # => ["name"]
claim.changes # => {"name" => ["Bill", "Bob"]}
```

Comment: This will not work after the model is saved which is what he asked for.

Comment: @TomRossi, the `dirty` calls works in `after_save`(both in Rails 2.3 and 3.x). I have used it several times.

Comment: @TomRossi, the dirty flags are reset after commit, so they wont be available in `after_commit` callbacks introduced in Rails 3.x. They certainly will work in `after_save`.

Comment: I had no idea!  I thought they were reset once it was saved!

Comment: @TomRossi I started with the same assumption few years ago. When I tried to check the dirty flags in after_save it worked. In essence, `after_save` is a callback for a state between `after DML` and `before_commit`. You can terminate the whole transaction in `after_save` by throwing an exception. If you want to do something after save with out affecting the current operation, use `after_commit` :-)

Comment: how to check if the nested model is updated or not?

Answer (score 38):

you can use this

```
self.changed
```

it return an array of all columns that changed in this record

you can also use

```
self.changes
```

which returns a hash of columns that changed and before and after results as arrays

Comment: Just a minor note to say that it is unnecessary to use `self.` on these -- you can just say `changed` and `changes`.

Comment: @user664833 More specifically, you can omit `self` when in the model itself, but you can call these on any object with `object.changed` and `object.changes`. :)

Answer (score 7):

For Rails 5.1+, you should use active record attribute method: [saved_change_to_attribute?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-saved_change_to_attribute-3F)

> **saved_change_to_attribute?**(attr_name, **options)`
>
> Did this attribute change when we last saved? This method can be
> invoked as `saved_change_to_name?` instead of
> `saved_change_to_attribute?("name")`. Behaves similarly to
> `attribute_changed?`. This method is useful in after callbacks to
> determine if the call to save changed a certain attribute.
>
> **Options**
>
> `from` When passed, this method will return false unless the original
> value is equal to the given option
>
> `to` When passed, this method will return false unless the value was
> changed to the given value

So your model will look like this, if you want to call some method based on the change in attribute value:

```
class Claim < ApplicationRecord
  
  after_save :do_this, if: Proc.new { saved_change_to_status?(from: nil, to: 'pending') }

  after_save :do_that, if: Proc.new { saved_change_to_status?(from: 'pending', to: 'approved') }

  
  def do_this
    ..
    ..
  end

  def do_that
    ..
    ..
  end

end
```

And if you don't want to check for value change in callback, you can do the following::

```
class Claim < ApplicationRecord

  after_save: :do_this, if: saved_change_to_status?


  def do_this
    ..
    ..
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you have a look at one of the available state machine plugins:

- [acts_as_state_machine](http://github.com/omghax/acts_as_state_machine/tree/master)
- [alter_ego](http://github.com/avdi/alter-ego/)

Either one will let you setup states and transitions between states. Very useful and easy way of handling your requirements.

Comment: I'm giving rubyist-aasm a try.

Lets say I have 

class Claim < ActiveRecord:: Base

  include AASM

  aasm_column :status
  aasm_initial_state :pending
  aasm_state :pending, :enter => :enter_pending

  def enter_pending
    Notifier.deliver_pending_notification(self)
  end

end

And my status field in my database has the default value of "pending".

If I were to do a Claim.create without filling in the status field (so that it will run 'pending'), will AASM run the 'enter_pending' method?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the question rise in many places, so I wrote a tiny rubygem for it, to make the code a little nicer (and avoid a million if/else statements everywhere): https://github.com/ronna-s/on_change.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will be much better off using a well tested solution such as the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem.