# rails custom validator to validate mime types with carrier wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, mime-types, carrierwave

I am using the following way to validate the mime type of uploaded file content with carrier wave.

https://gist.github.com/denyago/1298417

But this validation is running all the time even when no content is uploaded. This obviously fails as there is nothing to validate.

```
 validates :logo, :file_mime_type => {:content_type => /image/}
```

Is there any work around to skip validation when no content is uploaded?

Thanks !!

**UPDATE:**

Using the proc or lambda work well till there is no uploaded content present.

```
      ..., if => Proc.new{|company| company.logo.present?}

      @company.save #works will when @company contains correct mime type logo file 

      @company.save #fails when @company contains no logo file
```

As soon as someone uploads the logo it save the object correctly and starts raising wrong mime types exception on any other save where no image upload present.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add if condition. For example:

`validates :logo, :file_mime_type => {:content_type => /image/}, :if => Proc.new{|img| img.logo.present?}`

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this is not working if logo is already present in the application so that img.logo.present? returns true.

Comment: But you say that "no content is uploaded". Can you please clarify situation?

Comment: And if the logo is already present this validation should pass(unless your logo isn't valid. Do you have invalid records? which you can't update? )

Comment: No that is not the thing. Record is valid and content valid file type.

Comment: So why you want to skip validation if record is valid?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when I was trying to save the model that contained the carrierwave attribute, say the title of the image in your example.

```
validates :logo, :file_mime_type => { :content_type => /image/ },
:if => Proc.new{ |img| img.logo.present? and img.logo_changed? }
```

_changed? is available to tell if that specific attribute was changed: [How to detect attribute changes from model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586536/how-to-detect-attribute-changes-from-model)

Answer (score -1):

as stated in the doc for carrierwave.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only validate extension not the contents. you can upload video file as image just by changing the extension.