# How to validate a file as image on the server before uploading to S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3

The flow is:

- The user selects an image on the client.
- Only filename, content-type and size are sent to the server. (E.g. "file.png", "image/png", "123123")
- The response are fields and policies for upload directly to S3. (E.g. "key: xxx, "alc": ...)

The case is that if I change the extension of "file.pdf" to "file.png" and then uploads it, the data sent to the server before uploads to S3 are:

- "file.png"
- "image/png"

The servers says "ok" and return the S3 fields for upload .

But the content type sent is not a real content type. But how I can validate this on the server?

Thanks!

---

Example:

Testing Redactorjs server side code (https://github.com/dybskiy/redactor-js/blob/master/demo/scripts/image_upload.php) it checks the file content type. But trying upload fake image (test here: http://imperavi.com/redactor/), it not allows the fake image. Like I want!

But how it's possible? Look at the request params: (It sends as image/jpeg, that should be valid)

[image]

Comment: hope this will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768717/rails-custom-validator-to-validate-mime-types-with-carrier-wave

Comment: Actually not help too much. I'm not using carrierwave. But thanks!

Comment: So you're uploading straight to S3?

Comment: Yes. But before send I make an ajax call getting the policies to upload. This same ajax validates the params content-type. But it can be fake...

Answer (score 2):

When I was dealing with this question at work I found a solution using Mechanize.

Say you have an image url, `url = "http://my.image.com"`

Then you can use `img = Mechanize.new.get(url)[:body]`

The way to test whether `img` is really an image is by issuing the following test:

`img.is_a?(Mechanize::Image)`

If the image is not legitimate, this will return false.

There may be a way to load the image from file instead of URL, I am not sure, but I recommend looking at the mechanize docs to check.

Answer (score 1):

With older browsers there's nothing you can do, since there is no way for you to access the file contents or any metadata beyond its name.

With the HTML5 file api you can do better. For example,

```
document.getElementById("uploadInput").files[0].type
```

Returns the mime type of the first file. I don't believe that the method used to perform this identification is mandated by the standard.

If this is insufficient then you could read the file locally with the FileReader apis and do whatever tests you require. This could be as simple as checking for the magic bytes present at the start of various file formats to fully validating that the file conforms to the relevant specification. MDN has a great [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) that shows how to use various bits of these apis.

Ultimately none of this would stop a malicious attempt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I guess the only solution would be reading the first bytes in the server instead of the client I think