# decrement a value in view but not database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I have a total value that I would like to keep but I would also like to decrement it every time a certain kind of user creates the resource. For example I have-

```
if @user == "Premium"
        @resource.decrement!(:total)
end
```

But I would also like to show the first :total that I had. So in other words I would like the original value and the decremented value to show on the view page. like so-

```
<%= resource.total %>
<%= resource.decremented_value %>
```

how could I do that? Would I need to create another column in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @lukad03, 
I did some messing around with your answer and figured out another way myself. I created another column to mimic the first and just made it equal to itself in the resource model using a variable. (like @lukad03 said)

```
resource.rb

before_create :decrement

def decrement
self.total = self.decrement
end
```

It is a little bit of a hack but it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a separate column and then using a new method in your model to decrement the value. For example:

```
in models/resource.rb

before_create :decrement

def decrement
  self.decremented_value = self.total - 1
end
```

This will only call the decrement method when you create a Resource for the first time. If you edit an existing Resource's total however, it won't decrement the total as it's only listening for create actions. I would suggest looking at this answer for more on listening to updates in the model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586641/810794

One last thing: the naming of your `deceremented_value` and `total` columns is a little confusing. You may want to change them to `current_total` and `previous_total` as these seem to better describe what you're trying to achieve.