# unable to detect attribute changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Accoding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586536/how-to-detect-attribute-changes-from-model) stackoverflow post, I can use the following to detect attribute changes:

```
self.changes
```

And it *does* work when I use it in the model, such in an after_update callback:

```
  def check_activity
    changes = self.changes
    puts changes
  end
```

Unfortunately, it is not working in my controller update action. I tried to use it before the task was saved and after the task was saved:

```
  def update
    changes = @task.changes

    if @task.update_attributes(task_params)
      changes2 = @task.changes

      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated task."
      redirect_to polymorphic_path([@taskable, @task])
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately in both cases, it is empty:

```
Empty ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Just so you know, I am using load_and_authorize_resource provided by cancancan to load the resource @task.

Comment: In the first `changes` call, there aren't any because the object is still clean from the database without any changes touching it, the second call is after the data is already saved, so there's no changes either, because what changes were there were already saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any changes to show after you've made the change (IE update_attributes runs)

You could try using assign_attributes instead of update_attributes, checking that everything is valid (object.valid?) getting your changes and then saving

Answer (score 0):

Just check out `ActiveModel::Dirty`

Changes method does not returns changes after save.you should use it in before save, if you want to check the value after save use these ones `previous_changes` etc. for detail checkout `http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html.`