# Preferred way of handling actions in a rest api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

While working on my REST api, i was wondering what’s the best practice is, when you need to handle certain actions, let me explain with a example.

Say i got the following model.

```
  create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.float    "price"
    t.string   "status",            default: 'open'
    t.datetime "created_at",                    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    null: false
  end
```

I would then have the usual CRUD paths/actions (show, create, update, destroy) for that model.

Alright, say that i want to change the status of a given request record to 'accepted', i will sent my updated attributes to the update path, and wola.

But what if i wanted to react to certain status update, i might want to send mail to the involved users when the request updates.

**I could** create an entire new action for that behavior.

```
/api/v1/request/:id/approve
```

Then i could send my mail and update the status of the request in my action.

However i can't help but feel that i should be using the update function, as what i'm really doing is just updating the request status, the mail is more of a "side effect".

**Then i** had a look at [How to detect attribute changes from model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586536/how-to-detect-attribute-changes-from-model) which instead would let me pass the functionality to the model instead, sending a mail if the status changes before saving it.
However this will cause a lot of before actions, which i don't find particular pretty either.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the method that you have suggested would work fine in different scenarios:

1. Let say you have an application where any changes are very critical and should be notified immediately, then you can pass you mail functionality to your model and send the mail after you have updated the value.
2. If your changes are not that critical and it is ok if user gets notified after some time then you can

   I) You can either make an update call as you have suggested

   II) You can just add you mail functionality to a Queue, a sperate reader will read from the queue and send mail to users accordingly (This would be advantages if you have lot of users)

Answer (score 0):

What you may do (and what is a valid REST way I believe):

- Create a new controller called `RequestApproveController` or so.
- Create action `create` in that controller
- Create a method on your `Request` model named `approve` (in there update the attributes and send an email)
- Create a route which matches `/api/v1/request/:id/approve` to your `RequestApproveController`