# Updating attribute of model during before action when a different attribute changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, my model has these two relevant attributes: `first_id`, `second_id`

I'm trying to check that on update, if the `first_id` has changed, then set the `second_id` to `nil`, no matter what the value of `second_id` is.

So currently, my implementation in my model looks something like this:

```
  validates_presence_of :first_id
  before_action :check_if_first_id_changes, only: [:update]
  
  def check_if_first_id_changes
      if self.first_id != first_id
          # What do I insert here?
      end
  end
```

Is there any way I can do this in the model? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [How to detect attribute changes from model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586536/how-to-detect-attribute-changes-from-model)

Answer (score 3):

`before_action` is a controller method. You probably want to use `before_validation` or `before_save`.

The following should work for your requirements:

```
before_validation :update_second_id_when_first_id_changed, on: [:update]

private

def update_second_id_when_first_id_changed
  return unless first_id_changed?

  self.second_id = nil
end
```

Comment: Hmm, in my case, the user can update both first_id and second_id, but I just need to make sure that if first_id changes, whatever is saved in the database afterwards -- second_id must be nil. Why do you use self.second_id? Would it not be updated afterwards since i could be updating with a changed first_id, and a non-nil second_id. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment. What this code does: If the `first_id` didn't change then it returns immediately and does nothing (see [`DirtyAttributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) about how the `first_id_changed?` method works). But if `first_id` changed then `second_id` is set to `nil`. You need `self` here because otherwise, you would just set a `second_id` local variable but not the instance variable. This all happens before validation and before save, which means `second_id = nil` will be saved to the database automatically in the next step.

Comment: I think i had the misconception that `self.second_id` refers to the original value, while `second_id` refers to the new value that it would be updated to, hence I was wondering why you would do `self.second_id = nil` if it will just be updated to `second_id` after this `before_validation` method has finished. But yeap, your explanation makes it clear to me!

Answer (score 1):

The check `self.first_id != first_id` is never going to work, because they both reference the same value. You can use the helper `first_id_changed?` to check if there was a change made. The [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) documentation provides a list of all helpers regarding model instance attribute changes.

Like already pointed out, `before_action` is not valid in a model. You can check the available callbacks for models [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks). If there are no validations for `second_id` I would personally go for `before_update`, which removes the need to set the `on: :update` option.

I personally like to split up the "action" and "check" so you are able to call the action without the check blocking it. I would then combine the two in a callback definition. This is however just personal preference and you could easily move the check into the callback if that suits your needs better.

```rb
before_update :clear_second_id, if: :first_id_changed?

private

def clear_second_id
  self.second_id = nil
end
```