# Can I get the time from the status change without adding additional column or using updated_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[How to detect attribute changes from model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586536/how-to-detect-attribute-changes-from-model#new-answer) Relating to this question, can i see the time when the status is changed? please guide and help.

Comment: There are gems available for audit trails but these would add tables not just columns. Without persisting this data (e.g. adding a column or table) there is no way to tell when a specific event occurred (e.g. a status change) you can only tell when the record was created and when it was last updated, but not necessarily what was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize rails [Active Model Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) to check if a particular column in the model changed.

For example, imagine a `Car` class with a column `status` that you would like to observe. As Rails auto-generates the method `status_changed?`, you can use this as a conditional check to execute your custom method and read the time.

```rb
class Car
  before_update :my_custom_method, if: :status_changed?

  def my_custom_method
    # read the time
  end
end
```

Comment: I still needed to create a column in table. but your solution helped. thanks.